# Laptop is insanely freezing even after 100% fresh windows 10 OS installation, what are the possible fixes?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, dell-inspiron

**I'm writing this answer by renting another laptop for few hrs as my laptop is totally unusable, so if you want to ask any information, please tell it soon.**

Laptop Details:

Dell

Inspiron core i5 7th gen, 5567 laptop.

HDD=1TB

No SSD

8GB RAM. Another 8 GB slot available.

Bought in 2018

memtest86 done. No errors found.

I'll show what's actually happening in videos as it will be very hard for everyone to understand what I'm saying. The laptop is freezing too much. Even after fresh reinstall, the windows crashed once. I don't want to tell what's the BSOD, because it's meaningless in my experience. Nobody is going to read the MEMORY.DMP either. And all the different BSODs keep rotating. That one was PFN LIST CORRUPT.

I want to fix this urgently. Like some good fixes as I'd be busy for next 3 weeks and I'd need to keep using laptop till then. Tell me about it as well.

Here're the videos. These are in youtube so watch it with Wi-Fi only.

[First Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U5Yov0lcvw)

[I'm typing but it lags a lot to be displayed in browser and many](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHBrtO1K0C0)

[Task Manager 100% disk usage hinting need of SSD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_flfd92JMpU)

[Task Manager after around an hour after restarts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJZL5qAWi1Q)

What're some possible solutions that are quick and easy vs time consuming ones?

I've been planning since a long time to upgrade RAM to 8GB as I need to open 20+ tabs at once for my purpose of usage. As well as I'm pretty sure by now that SSD is utmost importance.

But I live in a high scam country. In a country with daylight robbery. There're no official dealers of anything(if any they're unusually expensive like 50x expensive than normal pricing in amazon). So, I've to be extra aware of where to purchase, what to purchase, how to test if the product is legit, Think about seducing the buyer into giving proper rates-google around the prices so that you know where's the cheapest. It's huge pain. There's no amazon here thus. Even better, our country doesn't allow importing products that easily and even if we do, the shipping will cost more than product as it's landlocked country.

So, I really don't want to do this now as I've no doubt at minimum it'd take me 1 week to do all these and I'm in emergency condition.

Any guidance?

**Edit:** I've looked at laptop's temperature, they're around 60 degree celsius.

**Edit 2:**

I did a BIOS diagnostic test. No issues found. It just told that battery didn't supply enough power which is normal. The charger is working alright.

[Here are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdiYM.jpg)

**Edit 3:**

I looked at Task Manager "performance" tab. The CPU speed was above 1 GHz in general. Here's 1 instant result.

[image: CPU Performance Tab]

[I saved video of it for 1 minute to see overall data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXecMEyXb3c)

**Edit 4.2:**

Here's the crystaldiskinfo one. I got it wrong for the first time(crystaldiskmark), this is it.

I'm not sure what is it saying. It says "good" but I can sense that my hard disk is today in the worst condition it has ever been in its life.

[image: Hard Drive CrystalDiskInfo]

---

Comment: Have you looked in the “bios” to see if there are any diagnostic tools built in? When rebooting you should see a prompt to press a key to enter setup

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event Viewer? It may be bad HDD, just one among the possibilities. Poor I/O can cause lag/freeze/BSOD etc. Check the HDD health by using tools like CrystalDiskInfo.

Comment: @JamesP No  issues in BIOS test.

Comment: Can you open task manager and look at the CPU frequency on the "performance" tab, is it stuck at 800MHz?

Comment: @Mokubai I posted the image above. It's usually above 1 GHz.

Comment: @patkim I haven't checked windows event viewer yet. But I did CrystalDiskInfo test for HDD health. You can see the results above in my edit. I've failed to interpret it due to the lack of benchmarks.

Comment: @patkim Eh sorry, earlier I posted crystaldiskmark, now I've posted crystaldiskinfo. It says "good" but the stats shown are worst for today. So, I get it died. My laptop just supports 1 drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is only one step to narrow down the cause. Most importantly you need to find out if it is caused by hardware or software. I recommend that you create an Ubuntu live usb and boot into that. It should work with even USB 2.0

This will help you find out some things:

Case 1) Good pc with bad drive or OS:

If your hard-drive or OS is bad (I doubt it would be the fresh win10 at fault, but still possible) the system should run fine from USB and even if a little scarry for a windows user to run Linux you could at least use your PC until you get a new HDD. (no changes or files will save between reboots, but you can still browse and use google drive or whatever)

Case 2) Bad pc hardware, good drive and OS:

If you get the same freezing or similar faults then you know that something is at fault in the laptop hardware. The things you described sound like a [RAM issue based on the symptoms](https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/bad-ram-symptoms.html), but it is strange that all tests are ok. I would recommend borrowing a compatible RAM stick to test with from somewhere, could be even from another laptop (just for booting and testing if that fixes it).

Then you can continue to narrow down the issue from there.

Comment: I've done memtest, crystalinfo disk health test, BIOS diagnostic. Hardware isn't faulty. Is it the OS then? I'm trying linux.

Comment: you never know until you try. I am just suggesting this method because it completely bypasses the drive and OS so this way you will know which side the problem is on.